# Как из HTTP запросa получить массив с информацией о контейнерах?

Tags: python, http, requests, proxmox

Средствами библиотеки `requests` пишу запрос к `proxmox` на получение информации о состоянии контейнеров:

```
zapros1 = requests.get('https://192.168.1.107:8006/api2/json/nodes/debprox/lxc', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, verify=False)
```

Исходя из документации, в качестве ответа я должен получить массив с информацией о контейнерах.

Вместо этого `print (zapros1)` выдает мне 200, а `print(type(zapros1))` выводит:

```
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
```

Что с этим делать? И как получить все же тот самый массив с информацией?

Comment: попробуйте `print (zapros1.json())`

Comment: по этому же запросу возник еще один вопрос, как сделать так что бы в строке адреса: https://192.168.1.107:8006/api2/json/nodes/debprox/lxc вместо nodes была переменная?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`requests.get()` возвращает объект типа `requests.models.Response`.

Если сайт возвращает JSON объект, то удобнее всего распарсить его используя метод `.json()`

```
r = requests.get(url)

if r.ok:
    data = r.json()
```